# SDDM Returning User Screen Does Not Respect Configurations

Tags: kde, sddm

Versions:

- `Kubuntu 22.10`
- `sddm 0.19.0-3ubuntu1`
- `kde-config-sddm 4:5.25.5-0ubuntu1`

I am using the KDE system settings to configure SDDM with a theme and background, and I have not done any other configuration besides that. After boot up, these settings are used, however when returning from sleep they are not. Instead, it uses the default breeze theme and a completely black wallpaper (but is still able to load my user icon). To clarify, every feature of the login screen works perfectly, just not the aesthetics. However, if I click "switch users" then my configurations are used immediately. Am I missing some setting somewhere, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, just a confusing part of KSystemSettings. The appearance for the global login screen (before user selection) is determined by `KSystemSettings > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen (SDDM)`. The appearance of the user-specific login screen (after logging in and then sleeping) is controlled by `KSystemSettings > Workspace Behavior > Screen Locking > Appearance: Configure`.